# How to run another macro but change the variable within it?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using this code to run another macro for `Fqty` times :

```
Dim Fqty As Integer
Dim PMT_Qty As Integer
Dim feeder As Integer

Fqty = Cells(14, 11).Value
PMT_Qty = Cells(15, 11).Value

For feeder = 1 To Fqty

    Call InsertRowsFeeder
    
Next feeder
```

The purpose of this is to create a table in a worksheet with `FQty` number of rows

However, I want to change a variable within `InsertRowsFeeder` to `PMT_Qty`. Can I do that?

Right now, that variable is set to a particular cell.

Comment: Modify `InsertRowsFeeder` to accept an argument.

Comment: You should rewrite `InsertRowsFeeder` with two parameters, one for the number of rows and one for `PMT_QTY`. No need for a loop here.

Comment: How can I make a macro accept an argument?

Comment: `Private Sub InsertRowsFeeder(ByVal Fqty As Long, ByVal PmtQty As Long)`.

Comment: Thanks BigBen, you're a homie

Comment: Well maybe `Public` instead of `Private`, but in any case, you get the point